# Synchronize outlook with Android calendar

Tags: java, outlook, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I would like bild app for synchronize android calendar with outlook calendar and counter.

This is my idea:

import outlook data with some API ([JaWin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/)) from MS Exchange server 
and then use CalDAV API for import on Android.

Is it possible? Or do you have other idea?

Thank you for help.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the Exchange Web Service (EWS) helpful. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information. You can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) and other web services in Exchange Online, Exchange Online as part of Office 365, or Exchange on-premises to create solutions that enable your users to access Exchange mailbox data from services, websites, desktop computers, and mobile devices.